# Adding A file to a Custom List using CSOM though visual-web-part

Tags: csom, visual-web-part

The web part consists of following elements:

1. a TextBox for Specifying the folder Name.
2. asp:FileUpload to fetch the file to be uploaded.
3. an asp:Button named Upload to upload the file. all the code needs to be written in its _click() event.

The web part has following elements

---

`<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Enter the Name of Document Library:-
        </td>
        <td title="Enter the Name of Document Library if left blank then Default Document Liberary">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtLibraryName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Enter the Date of Document:-
        </td>
        <td title="Enter the Date of Document if left blank then random Date">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Browse the File:-
        </td>
        <td title="Browse the File if not then no file will be uploaded only a folder will be created">
            <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload" runat="server" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br />
<asp:Button ID="btnFileUpload" runat="server" Text='Upload "File" to a "Folder"' OnClick="btnFileUpload_Click" />`

---

I have done the above program in SharePoint SSOM
`

```
    protected void btnFileUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Web initilization
        SPSite site = new SPSite("http://spappdc:33333/sites/Access");
        SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();
        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

        //Check Date TextBox
        CheckLibrary(web);

        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
    }
```

`

`

```
    public void CheckLibrary(SPWeb web)
    {

        //Check Library TextBox
        if (txtLibraryName.Text == "")
        {
            //Get Default Document Library
            SPList documentLibrary = web.Lists.TryGetList("Documents");
            //Check Month Folder Exists
            CheckFolderExists(web, documentLibrary);
        }
        else
        {
            //Check if Library exists
            if (web.Lists.TryGetList(txtLibraryName.Text) == null)
            {
                //Create New Library
                Guid documentLibraryID = web.Lists.Add(txtLibraryName.Text, "", SPListTemplateType.DocumentLibrary);
                SPList documentLibrary = web.Lists[documentLibraryID];
                //Check Month Folder Exists
                CheckFolderExists(web, documentLibrary);
            }
            else
            {
                //Get the Library
                SPList documentLibrary = web.Lists.TryGetList(txtLibraryName.Text);
                //Check Month Folder Exists
                CheckFolderExists(web, documentLibrary);
            }
        }
    }
```

`

`

```
    //Get Date
    private string FolderName()
    {
        Random randomNo = new Random();

        int month = txtDate.Text == "" ? 1 : int.Parse(txtDate.Text.Split('/')[1]) == 12 ? 1 : int.Parse(txtDate.Text.Split('/')[1]) + 1;
        int year = txtDate.Text == "" ? 1990 : month == 1 ? int.Parse(txtDate.Text.Split('/')[2]) + 1 : int.Parse(txtDate.Text.Split('/')[2]);
        string folderName;
        txtDate.Text = "01/" + month.ToString() + "/" + year.ToString();
        string monthName = string.Empty;
        switch (month)
        {
            case 1:
                monthName = "Jan";
                break;
            case 2:
                monthName = "Feb";
                break;
            case 3:
                monthName = "Mar";
                break;
            case 4:
                monthName = "Apr";
                break;
            case 5:
                monthName = "May";
                break;
            case 6:
                monthName = "Jun";
                break;
            case 7:
                monthName = "Jul";
                break;
            case 8:
                monthName = "Aug";
                break;
            case 9:
                monthName = "Sep";
                break;
            case 10:
                monthName = "Oct";
                break;
            case 11:
                monthName = "Nov";
                break;
            case 12:
                monthName = "Dec";
                break;
        }
        return folderName = monthName + "-" + year;
    }
```

`

`

```
    //Check Month Folder Exists
    public void CheckFolderExists(SPWeb web, SPList documentLibrary)
    {
        string folderName = FolderName();
        if (web.GetFolder(documentLibrary.RootFolder.Url + "/" + folderName).Exists)
        {
            //Folder Exists Upload File
            SPFolder libraryMonthFolder = web.GetFolder(documentLibrary.RootFolder.Url + "/" + folderName);
            UploadFile(libraryMonthFolder, documentLibrary);
        }
        else
            //Create Folder And Upload
            CreateNewFolderAndUpload(documentLibrary, folderName);
        documentLibrary.Update();
    }
```

`

`

```
    //Create Folder And Upload
    public void CreateNewFolderAndUpload(SPList documentLibrary, string folderName)
    {
        SPFolder libraryMonthFolder = documentLibrary.RootFolder.SubFolders.Add(documentLibrary.RootFolder.Url + "/" + folderName);
        libraryMonthFolder.Update();
        UploadFile(libraryMonthFolder, documentLibrary);
    }
```

`

`

```
    //Upload File In Folder
    private void UploadFile(SPFolder libraryMonthFolder, SPList documentLibrary)
    {
        //upload only if file is browsed
        if (FileUpload.HasFile)
        {
            libraryMonthFolder.Files.Add(libraryMonthFolder.Url + "/" + FileUpload.FileName, FileUpload.FileBytes, true);
            libraryMonthFolder.Update();
        }
    }
```

`

Comment: Please provide your efforts that you have tried before. Your code or something.

Comment: Your question is not clear, Are you facing any issue? any error? What exactly is the question

Comment: @DikeshGandhi updated the question

Comment: @Gaurravs the question is that I have done the program in SSOM as above mentioned and it is working fine but facing problems while doing it using CSOM

Comment: You want same code in CSOM ?

Comment: what CSOM code you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most Probable Answer in CSOM Similar to your SSOM Code could be

`Select Date:<asp:TextBox ID="dateTxt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br /><br />
Add file:<asp:FileUpload ID="fileUpload" runat="server" /><br /><br />
<asp:Button ID="Savebtn" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="Savebtn_Click" /><br /><br />
<asp:Label ID="msgLbl" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>`

`

```
    protected void Savebtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        InputValid inputValid = new InputValid();
        if (inputValid.IsInputValid(dateTxt, fileUpload))
        {
            ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("http://spappdc:55555/sites/MyKM/Stocks");
            SecureString password = new SecureString();
            foreach (char a in "Zest@12345".ToCharArray())
                password.AppendChar(a);
            clientContext.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("administrator", password, "SHAREPOINT");

            Web web = clientContext.Web;
            Web rootweb = clientContext.Site.RootWeb;

            List documentLibrary = web.Lists.GetByTitle("NewLibrary");
            GetTxtboxValue getTxtValue = new GetTxtboxValue();
            getTxtValue.TxtboxValues(documentLibrary, web, clientContext, rootweb, dateTxt, fileUpload, msgLbl);
        }
        else
        {
            msgLbl.Text = "Please enter valid input!!";
            msgLbl.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }

    }
```

`

`

```
class InputValid
{
    public bool IsInputValid(TextBox dateTxt, FileUpload fileUpload)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dateTxt.Text))
            return false;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileUpload.FileName))
            return false;

        return true;
    }
}
```

```
class GetTxtboxValue
{
    public void TxtboxValues(List documentLibrary, Web web, ClientContext clientContext, Web rootWeb, TextBox dateTxt, FileUpload fileUpload, Label msgLbl)
    {

        //Get the value from textbox 
        string txtValue = dateTxt.Text;
        string date = txtValue.Split('/')[0];
        string month = txtValue.Split('/')[1];
        string year = txtValue.Split('/')[2];
        string monthName = string.Empty;
        switch (month)
        {
            case "01":
                monthName = "January";
                break;
            case "02":
                monthName = "February";
                break;
            case "03":
                monthName = "March";
                break;
            case "04":
                monthName = "April";
                break;
            case "05":
                monthName = "May";
                break;
            case "06":
                monthName = "June";
                break;
            case "07":
                monthName = "July";
                break;
            case "08":
                monthName = "August";
                break;
            case "09":
                monthName = "September";
                break;
            case "10":
                monthName = "October";
                break;
            case "11":
                monthName = "November";
                break;
            case "12":
                monthName = "December";
                break;
        }
```

```
        clientContext.Load(documentLibrary.RootFolder.Folders);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        Folder folder = documentLibrary.RootFolder.Folders[0];
        bool isFolderPresent = false;
        foreach (Folder fld in documentLibrary.RootFolder.Folders)
            if (fld.Name == monthName + "-" + year)
            {
                folder = fld;
                isFolderPresent = true;
            }
        FolderCreationAndFileUpload fldCreate = new FolderCreationAndFileUpload();
        if (isFolderPresent == false)
        {
            //create newFile and assning to folder

            fldCreate.FolderCreation(clientContext, documentLibrary, monthName, year, fileUpload);
            msgLbl.Text = "Folder Created And File Uploaded";
        }
        else
        {
            //upload file in existing one

            fldCreate.UploadFile(clientContext, folder, fileUpload);
            msgLbl.Text = "File Uploaded in Existing One ";
        }
    }
}
```

```
class FolderCreationAndFileUpload
{
    public void FolderCreation(ClientContext clientContext, List documentLibrary, string monthName, string year, FileUpload fileUpload)
    {
        documentLibrary.EnableFolderCreation = true;
        documentLibrary.Update();
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        clientContext.Load(documentLibrary.RootFolder); clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        Folder docLibraryFolder = documentLibrary.RootFolder.Folders.Add(documentLibrary.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl + "/" + monthName + "-" + year);
        clientContext.Load(docLibraryFolder); clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        docLibraryFolder.Update();

        UploadFile(clientContext, docLibraryFolder, fileUpload);
        documentLibrary.Update();

    }
    public void UploadFile(ClientContext clientContext, Folder docLibraryFolder, FileUpload fileUpload)
    {
        FileCreationInformation fileInfo = new FileCreationInformation
        {
            Content = fileUpload.FileBytes,
            Overwrite = true,
            Url = docLibraryFolder.ServerRelativeUrl + "/" + fileUpload.FileName,

        };
        clientContext.Load(docLibraryFolder.Files); clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        docLibraryFolder.Files.Add(fileInfo);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        docLibraryFolder.Update();
    }
}
```

`